# Make a link to the file so that enviroment can find it

Tags: software-installation, symlink

I am installing a [program](https://github.com/szaghi/MaTiSSe/wiki/Manual-Installation) following instructions

> What you need for a manual installation is the subdirectory MaTiSSe-vx.x.x under the release directory (chose the version x.x.x you want). Just copy this subdirectory and make a link to the wrapper script MaTiSSe.py where your environment can find it.

I don't know how to make it with command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would interpret the instructions as *create a link to the wrapper script in a place where it would be accessible through your `$PATH`*.

If your path contains something like

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

I would create the link in, e.g., `/usr/local/bin`:

```
ln -s /some/path/MaTiSSe-vx.x.x/wrapper-script /usr/local/bin/matisse
```

Alternatively, just add the `MaTiSSe-vx.x.x` directory to your path in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH="$PATH:/some/path/MaTiSSe-vx.x.x"
```

and then use the name of the wrapper script on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the command to make a link to a file is

```
ln -s <path to file> <path to link>
```

Comment: Great! I know the path to the file, Then what is the path to the link?

Comment: Where can your environment find files such as these? That is the directory where you want to put your link.

Comment: Okay, How can I know where is the place that my environment can find? that's my problem.

Comment: If it means what I think it means, then the most common location where your environment can find it is usually /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin. You can also make a bin folder in your home directory and place it there.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it. `copy this subdirectory and make a link to the wrapper script MaTiSSe.py where your environment can find it.` . I do `sudo ln -s MaTiSSe-v0.0.2/ /usr/bin/` then I execute `MaTiSSe.py` It says `MaTiSSe.py: command not found`

Comment: Have you tried executing it without the file extension? Like, just doing `MaTiSSe`? I don't think the environment cares for file extensions. And check to make sure using a file explorer that it properly linked.